# Using DOMXpath how do I loop through the DOM and stop at the first piece of text?

Tags: php, xpath

I was to use DOMXpath to loop through the nodes of a DOM and stops when it gets to the first piece of text.

So with this method I can capture and delete the first lot of line breaks but leave the rest after hello world:

```
$html = '<br><br><br>Hello World<br><br><br>'
```

I'm not sure what the $xpath query is to find plain text but I imaging the code would be something like this:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
showDOMNode($doc);
$i = 1;
$dom_xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
foreach($nodes as $node) {
  do {
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node); 
   } while ($i > 0);
  if($node == $xpath->query("/:TEXT")){
      $i = 0;
  }
}
```

Just a rough piece of code but imagine what I want is something like that, could somebody fill in the gaps for me please.

Comment: In your example, `//br[not(preceding::text())]` would select all `<br>` elements that don't have a text node before them somewhere in the document.  You could then remove those elements.  But i imagine your real requirements are a little more significant than that...and the more you care about, the more complicated a pure XPath selector would be.

Comment: @cHao Hmm, interesting, let me play with that for a minute, it's certainly the best (only) response I've had so far :) thanks.

Comment: @cHao Question, in my example, is "hello world" still inside a node even if it's not wrapped in any <p> tags, if so which node is it in?

Comment: Everything in the document is a node -- even naked text.  "Hello World" is a text node, and will have the same parent as the `<br>` elements around it -- which, in your example, should be the `<body>` element.

Comment: @cHao You glorious bastard, I think this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$doc->loadHTML($html);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
    foreach($xpath->query('//br[not(preceding::text())]') as $node) {
        $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
    }
    return $doc->saveHTML();
```

@cHao the man!